# Converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchEmployee
        @EmployeeID int,
        @EmployeeName nvarchar(256),
        @Address nvarchar(256),
AS
    Select 
        EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Address 
    From 
        Employee
    Where
        EmployeeID = @EmployeeID OR
        EmployeeName LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName+ '%' OR
        Address LIKE '%' + @Address+ '%'
```

Then in my Winforms I call it like this:

```
using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.SearchEmployee", myDatabaseConnection))
{
            mySqlCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            {
                mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
                mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", textBox1.Text);
                mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
```

How I will avoid the error

> Error converting data type  nvarchar to int.

When a user type a employee name instead of `EmployeeID`?

I tried this in my stored procedure:

```
EmployeeID = cast(@EmployeeID as varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your design. How can you use same field from `Name` and `Id` ? `Name` can contain any character where as `Id` can't!. Fastest workaround would be pass invalid value for `Id` if user types non numeric.

```
int empId = 0;
if(!int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out empId))
{
    empId = -1;// or some invalid Id which won't appear in DB
}
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", empId);
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: Because I will be only using one searchTextBox that will find on each field. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this implementation instead:

- Create two different stored procedures - one for numeric IDs, another for alphanumeric queries;
- Detect, on your Winforms application, if the content typed by the user is numeric or not - you may check [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to implement this;
- Use one or the other, according to input type.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", textBox1.Text);
```

to

```
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID",Convert.ToInt32( textBox1.Text));
```